# Am I able to use a logic function (and, or) between 2 comparisons

Tags: delphi, logic, delphi-xe

I am unsure whether it is generally impossible to use a logic function between to comparisons or if I've used my logic statement incorrectly because when I make all variables (NewUsername, NewUsername2, NewPass, NewPass2) to the characters "hi", it would continue to display the Application.MessageBox.

```
    procedure TNewUserFrm.ApplyBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if (NewUsername <> NewUsername2) or (NewPass <> NewPass2) then
      begin
        Application.MessageBox('The usernames or passwords do not match. Try again', 'Error');
      end
      else
      begin
        if not modFile.UsersDataSet.Active then modFile.UsersDataSet.Open;
        modFile.UsersDataSet.Append;
        modFile.UsersDataSet.FieldByName('Username').AsString := NewUsername.Text;
        modFile.UsersDataSet.FieldByName('Password').AsString := NewPass.Text;
        modFile.UsersDataSet.Post;
        NewUserFrm.Hide;
      end;
      NewUsername.Text := '';
      NewUsername2.Text := '';
      NewPass.Text := '';
      NewPass2.Text := '';
      ApplyBtn.SetFocus;
    end;
```

I have tried using "and" statement, "or" statement and I've also tried using nested "if" statements instead but the same result occurs

Comment: FWIW, `and`, `or` and `xor` are logical as well as bitwise *operators*, not *functions* or *statements*. If you want to discuss code, try to get your terms right.

Comment: Alright sorry. I just forgot the word for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparing the TEdit controls addresses, not their content. You need to compare their contents.

```
if (NewUsername.Text <> NewUsername2.Text) or (NewPass.Text <> NewPass2.Text) then
```

Writing something like

```
NewUsername <> NewUsername2
```

will always have the value true in this case because these are two different TEdit controls, and their addresses will never be the same.

Comment: Good catch! I thought they were string variables.